# How to control a rotating joint in velocity

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-control, transmission

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm trying to control a rotating joint type "`continuous`" in velocity, and simulate it in Gazebo.

This is the URDF joint definition:

```
<joint name="${name}_joint" type="continuous"> 
      <xacro:insert_block name="origin" />
      <parent link="${namespace}/${parent}"/>
      <child link="${namespace}/${name}"/>
      <axis xyz="1 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <limit effort="2000.0" velocity="40.0" />
    </joint>

    <gazebo>
      <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
        <robotNamespace>${namespace}</robotNamespace>
      </plugin>
    </gazebo>

    <transmission name="${name}_joint_trans">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="${name}_joint">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="${name}_joint_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      </actuator>
    </transmission>
```

and the config yaml file for controllers:

```
 joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 60

  my_joint_position_controller:
    type: velocity_controllers/JointVelocityController
    joint: my_joint
    pid: {p: 0.5, i: 0.6, d: 0.0035}
```

I have couple of questions:

- first, can someone explain the `yaml` file or give a tutorial explaining this? what is "`publish_rate`" and what is its role?  how can influence the rotation?
  same for "`joint_state_controller`"?
- Second, to change the joint velocity I run :

  rostopic pub /my_joint_position_controller/command std_msgs/Float64 "data: 5.0"

  the data value is a linear velocity (m/s) or rotational velocity (rad/s) ?
  If it is a linear velocity, how can I transform that to rotational velocity (rad/s)?
- third, how can I get the joint angle at every moment?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338981/how-to-control-a-rotating-joint-in-velocity/) by [lotfishtaine](https://answers.ros.org/users/27094/lotfishtaine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2019-12-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lotfishtaine](https://answers.ros.org/users/27094/lotfishtaine/) on 2019-12-04**:
In my implementation, I followed this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control) and managed to control the joint. However, when I get to the controller performance visualization part, I can't find the topic `my_joint_position_controller/state/process_value`

Does this mean that I'm missing something in my implementation?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-04**:
`state/process_value` is not a topic. It's a field in the message that is published on the `state` topic.

See also #q323036.

`rqt_plot` is just able to "reach into" messages to plot values from fields. That makes it seem like they are topics, but they're not (`rostopic` can do the same).

**Comment by [lotfishtaine](https://answers.ros.org/users/27094/lotfishtaine/) on 2019-12-04**:
Thank you for your reply.
When you said `state` topic, do you mean `/joint_states` topic or another topic?
`rostopic list` command only gives me one topic related to my joint controller:

```
- `my_joint_position_controller/command`
```

Should I have another topic or not?
like :

```
  - my_joint_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
  - my_joint_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
  - my_joint_position_controller/state
```

same in this [example](https://www.theconstructsim.com/my-robotic-manipulator-04-urdf-transmission-gazebo-controllers/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1- the `yaml` file is basically describe the used controllers. It always contains the `joint_state_controller` which is in charge of providing constant information about the state of the joint, and the description of the other controllers. The `/joint_states` topic is published by an instance of the `JointStateController`. This is a read-only controller that does not command any joint, but rather publishes the current joint states at a configurable frequency (`publish_rate`).

2- the inputs to ros controllers are always in SI units, so a joint velocity controller will accept  radians per second.

3- `joint_state_controller`: it continuously provides the state of the joint.

4- for the question in the comment, I think that it is a bug with `velocity_controllers` which prevent the topic `my_joint_position_controller/state` to be published. I changed the controller to `effort_controllers/JointVelocityController` and I get this topic.

5- a nice tutorial explaining `ros_control` can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZGNIVFqXI8&feature=youtu.be).

---

Originally posted by [lotfishtaine](https://answers.ros.org/users/27094/lotfishtaine/) with karma: 76 on 2019-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0